# Parameterize id names

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a better way of doing this? Hopefully, to shorten the lines?

```
when (tabKey) {
        1 -> {
            learnHeader!!.id        = R.id.learnHeader1
            learnSwipeRefresh!!.id  = R.id.learnSwipeRefresh1
        }

        2 -> {
            learnHeader!!.id        = R.id.learnHeader2
            learnSwipeRefresh!!.id  = R.id.learnSwipeRefresh2           
        }
}
```

Something like:

```
            learnHeader!!.id        = R.id.learnHeader + tabKey
            learnSwipeRefresh!!.id  = R.id.learnSwipeRefresh + tabKey
```

Comment: I don't recommend it but you can retrieve identifiers by name. [`context.resources.getIdentifier("learnHeader$tabKey", "layout", context.packageName )`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ....

```
int idHeader[]={R.id.learnHeader1,R.id.learnHeader2};
int idSwipeRefresh[]={R.id.learnSwipeRefresh1,R.id.learnSwipeRefresh2};



tabKey--;

learnHeader!!.id        =idHeader[tabKey]
learnSwipeRefresh!!.id  = idSwipeRefresh[tabKey]
```

Hope it help you.....